# How can I convert the unix date values along the axis of a d3.js graph to format dd-mm-yy?

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, unix-timestamp

I currently have my data feeding into the table with unix date format, but I'm having trouble reformatting the unix dates to any other format, such as dd-mm-yy.

I currently have the below, and have been trying to edit the area under  xAxis = d3.svg.axis()

```
var vis = d3.select("#visualization"),
  WIDTH = 800,
  HEIGHT = 500,
  MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
  xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function(d) {
    return d.date;
   }), d3.max(lineData, function(d) {
    return d.date;
    })]),
  yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function(d) {
   return d.weight;
 }), d3.max(lineData, function(d) {
  return d.weight;
  })]),
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xRange)
  .tickSize(10)
  .tickSubdivide(true),
yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yRange)
  .tickSize(20)
  .orient('left')
  .tickSubdivide(true);
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is (depending on the length of your data) iterate over it before you do any d3 drawing and cast the date field of your data objects to a formatted date. I say depending on the length of your data because if it is very long and you are actually rendering a page, you would want to avoid going over it twice and you could probably do this step when you are going over all your data.foreach and actually appending stuff to a svg/g/line, what have you. I like to do it separate for readability.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

data.forEach(function(d){               

    var timestamp= new Date(d.timestamp * 1000);
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var month = months[timestamp.getMonth()];
    var date = timestamp.getDate();
    var year = timestamp.getFullYear()-2000;

    var formatted_time = date + '-'+ month + '-' + year;

    d['date']= parseDate(formatted_time);


});
```

This should get you started. In the case here, I have the timestamp as an integer, and depending on the precision you may or may not want to multiply it by 1000. `%b` is the d3 syntax for a named month abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with time data, try using D3's built-in time scale ([`d3.time.scale`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales)) instead of the linear scale (where you have `xRange = d3.scale.linear`). You can then provide the axis with a time format for its ticks (as in, `xAxis.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y"))`), without needing to do any iteration over the data set.